# MongoDB/JS: How to get all unique string values of array field

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor

I need to get all unique values of the arrays of each selected document from mongoDB (using meteorJS and this has to be done on server side).

**datastructure**

```
{ 
  _id: 'Wt7gSvxSPbRw46KHK',
  parent: 'doxCi4MSNmFJE43EH',
  target: [ 'ejiSooMx6czQxzWmW', 'Q297RZEYKJdWWRyTJ' ] 
}
```

This is my query and `target` is an array with string elements.

**query**

```
Collection.find(
  { parent: parent, target: { $exists: true } },
  { field: { target: 1 } }
).map(doc => { return doc.target })
```

Right now my result of this query would look like this:

```
[ 
  [ 'Q297RZEYKJdWWRyTJ' ],
  [ 'Q297RZEYKJdWWRyTJ', 'ejiSooMx6czQxzWmW' ],
  [ 'ejiSooMx6czQxzWmW', 'Q297RZEYKJdWWRyTJ' ],
  [ 'ejiSooMx6czQxzWmW' ] 
]
```

The first problem for me is to map the content of the arrays not the arrays itself, which should look like this:

```
[ 
  'Q297RZEYKJdWWRyTJ',
  'Q297RZEYKJdWWRyTJ', 'ejiSooMx6czQxzWmW',
  'ejiSooMx6czQxzWmW', 'Q297RZEYKJdWWRyTJ',
  'ejiSooMx6czQxzWmW' 
]
```

And at least the result should have unique values:

```
[ 'Q297RZEYKJdWWRyTJ', 'ejiSooMx6czQxzWmW' ]
```

Comment: Can you add a sample doc? from that collection? it will be really helpful to answer to your question.

Comment: added data structure to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
var uniqArray = [].concat.apply([],
  Collection.find(
    { parent: parent, target: { $exists: true } },
    { field: { target: 1 } }
  ).map(doc => doc.target )
).reduce((acc,curr) => (acc.indexOf(curr) === -1) ? acc.concat(curr) : acc,[])
```

Returns this:

```
[
    "Q297RZEYKJdWWRyTJ",
    "ejiSooMx6czQxzWmW"
]
```

Which is what you are asking for.

Alternately you should be able to use `.rawCollection()` and `.distinct()`

```
var uniqArray = Collection.rawCollection().distinct("target",{
  parent: parent, target: { "$exists": true }
})
```

Comment: @user3142695 It does for me. And basically if I just replace the `Collection.find()` statement with the "array of arrays" in your current output, then the desired output is exactly what I get.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter for getting unique array elements

```
var unique = array.filter(function(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) to solve this cleanly, and it is already included in [meteor](http://docs.meteor.com/packages/underscore.html)

```
_.chain( Collection.find({ parent: parent, target: { $exists: true } }).fetch() )
 .pluck('target')
 .flatten()
 .value();
```